# Can we prove that $\operatorname{rad}(ABC)^2-C$ is not a square when $A+B=C$ are coprime integers?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, abc-conjecture

A weak form of the ABC conjecture states that $\operatorname{rad}(ABC)^2-C$ is always positive. Here the radical of a positive integer $n$, denoted $\operatorname{rad}(n)$, is the product of the distinct prime factors of $n$. For instance $\operatorname{rad}(20)=2.5=10$. Note that for coprime numbers $A,B$ we have $\operatorname{rad}(AB)=\operatorname{rad}(A).\operatorname{rad}(B)$.

**Can we show that $\operatorname{rad}(ABC)^2-C$ is not a square?**

If it would be a square, we would have $\operatorname{rad}(ABC)^2-C=t^2$ for some positive integer $t$. As the left side is divisible by $\operatorname{rad}(C)$, it follows that $t^2$, and hence $t$, is divisible by $\operatorname{rad}(C)$. Rewriting yields $\operatorname{rad}(AB)^2-\frac{C}{\operatorname{rad}(C)^2}=(\frac{t}{\operatorname{rad}(C)})^2$. This implies that $C$ is a [powerful number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerful_number).

I checked the statement for $C \le 1000000$ using [Sage](https://www.sagemath.org/).

I tried [modular arithmatic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) to proof the statement, but it seems not a successful approach. Modulo 24 for instance gives a simple table based on the divisibility by 2 and 3:

$$\begin{array}{|c||c|c|} \hline
rad(AB)^2 & \text{uneven} & \text{even} \\ \hline \hline
\text{factor 3} & 9 & 12 \\ \hline
\text{no factor 3} & 1 & 4 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Unfortunally, this split seems not very helpful.

Comment: In the title you wrote that $A+B=C$.  But you did not write this in the question itself. My question: $A+B=C$ ?

Comment: @Witold Yes, $A+B=C$.